# unity C# how to get the camera to floow the player between scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

In my unity project I have 1 scene a main camera with code for it to not be destroyed on scene load and code for it to follow the player and the player has code to prevent it being destroyed on scene load. The problem is the camera follows the player in scene one but stops following them in scene 2 however the camera is still there.

Initially I was using cinemachine to make the camera follow the player with the stay loaded upon scene transiton code but that wouldnt work either so I changed it to code on the main camera that gets it to follow the player.

Heres the current code for the camera follow player script:

```
public class CameraFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0f, 0f, -10f);
    private float smoothTime = 0.25f;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    [SerializeField] private Transform target;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = target.position + offset;
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
    }
}
```

heres the code for the cameras dont destroy upon load code:

```
public class Cameradontdestroy : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static Cameradontdestroy Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        //prevents 2 instances of the camera existing at any given time
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

heres the code for the player dont destroy on load:

```
public static BasicPlayerMovement Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        //prevents 2 instances of the player existing at any given time
        if(Instance != null && Instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: I've been following this tutorial.  This link shows how to pan the camera between 2 areas of a scene.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PA5DgZfRsAM&ab_channel=Pandemonium

Comment: I imagine `target` is being lost. Assign it again via `Start` / `GameObject.Find`

Comment: sorry the video isn't exactly what im looking for because it isn't between scenes and the code in the start function won't run when I enter a new scene